# Are the returned values of a static object thread safe in java

Tags: java, thread-safety

Let us assume an object as follows:

```
My Object { 
private String field1 = "";
private  String field2 = "";

/*getters and setters for field1 and field2 */

boolean isField1inDocument (String document) {
      if (document.indexOf(field1) > -1) return true;
      else return false;
 }

}
```

Is the method isField1inDcoument thread safe?    I am worried that the boolean value returned by one thread may some how collide with the boolean value created by another thread executing the method at the same time.   The documents being fed to the method are from individual threads and the documents themselves can't collide.    I know I can synchronize this method. I'm just trying to figure out if this is necessary.

Comment: What do you refer with "static object"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logically the behavior of isField1inDocument() is dependent on only the document (which you say is only owned by the thread), and the value of field1. You do have setters for field 1 so it's possible to imagine a scenario where field1 is altered by a different thread while your current thread is doing your isField1inDocument() calculation, so that's not thread safe.

You could fix this by passing in the field1 value, e.g.

```
boolean isField1inDocument (String document, String field1){...
```

or by holding a private instance of the enclosing MyObject from the caller thread

```
new MyObject().isField1InDocument(document)
```

Comment: Are multiple threads calling the same method, creating separate instances of the method so that what ever values returned by that method are kept thread safe?

Comment: It's not a question of the instance of the method, it's the data that the method accesses. So your initial method is unsafe because it's accessing a shared data variable. There's no issue with the actual parameter (document), if that's what you're concerned about - the method parameter is being acted on in the context of the method scope of this invocation and will not interact with another thread calling the same method, even on the same instance.You'd only get into trouble if multiple threads can act on the same data(for example, if your class held a shared reference to the document object).

Answer (score 1):

No this is not thread safe.

Reason being it is accessing field1 which is an instance variable, other threads can modify field1 while it is being accessed inside your method, resulting in incorrect computation.

Fixing this issue can be done multiple ways,

- Pass field1 as part of your parameter

  boolean isField1inDocument (String document, String field1)

In this case since methods live on Stack and for every thread there is a separate Stack no issue of thread interleaving.

- Synchronize your code, so that only one thread can access field1, so the setter method for `field1` and `isField1inDocument` should both be synchronized on the same object. Synchronization causes decrease in through put so you will have to be careful when doing so.
- If you can make field1 final, in this case it cannot be initialized and your concern about thread safety is taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

This method will become thread safe if you declare field as final, then there will not be a possibility of field one getting modified